# Program calculating minimum amount of coins is correct when integer is input, but not a float

Tags: python-3.x

I have a homework assignment in which I have to write a program that outputs the change to be given by a vending machine using the lowest number of coins. E.g. £3.67 can be dispensed as 1x£2 + 1x£1 + 1x50p + 1x10p + 1x5p + 1x2p.

This program works when I input 230 instead of 2.3, for example, but when I put change=change*100 in my program (which should do the same thing), my answers are inaccurate - probably due to some rounding error.

```
change=float(input("Input change"))
(change=change*100)
denominations = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
used = {x: 0 for x in denominations}

for val in denominations:
    used[val] += change // val
    change -= val * used[val]

print(used)
```

WITHOUT change=change*100:

```
Input: 230
Output: {200: 1.0, 100: 0.0, 50: 0.0, 20: 1.0, 10: 1.0, 5: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 1: 0.0}
i.e. 230
```

WITH change=change*100:

```
Input: 2.3
Output: {200: 1.0, 100: 0.0, 50: 0.0, 20: 1.0, 10: 0.0, 5: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 1: 0.0}
i.e. 2.29 (and using far too many coins)
```

Comment: You should use int instead of float to avoid this problem ; you don't need any decimal here for your problem.

Comment: I agree with @politinsa, the best solution is just to take input in `p` (i.e. as an integer). if it is an assignment defined otherwise, then you should use `decimal.Decimal` for round-accurate floating math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for higher precision decimal math, you can use the [dedicated library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

please try this:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

change=Decimal(input("Input change"))
change=change*100
denominations = [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
used = {x: 0 for x in denominations}

for val in denominations:
    used[val] += int(change / val)
    change -= val * used[val]

print(used)
print("TOTAL:", sum([val * used[val] for val in denominations]))
```

NOTE: your algorithm is greedy, and correct for the current `denominations` and for most coin systems in the world, but not always. so if as part of the assignment you might be tested against some arbitrary coin system - it might not work (e.g with `denominations = [240,60,30,24,12,6,3,1]`, your answer for `48` will be `30+12+6` whereas it should be `24+24`)

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, although it printed out slightly weirdly.